# Siunitx table, with a number in parentheses (single row)

Tags: tables, beamer, siunitx, brackets

I want a table column to be aligned using the thousands comma. But when I try to put a number in parentheses I get an error.

I have read previous answers which were not suitable for my situation, either because they answered a situation where the whole column needed parentheses, or because they wrote `input-symbols = {()},` which then counts the parentheses as digits.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=5.0]S[table-format = 1.1]}
            12000             & 1.4 \\
            (14000) & 1.2 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**: Upon further review, there is a better option. `siunitx` provides the `table-space-text-pre` and `table-space-text-post` options for precisely this use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
        group-separator={,},
    ]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=5.0, table-space-text-pre={(}, table-space-text-post={)}] S[table-format=1.1]}
        12000   &   1.4 \\
        {(} 14000 {)}   &   1.2 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

---

*[original answer]*

The easiest possibility is probably placing the parentheses in the table margins using `\llap` and `\rlap`. We can hide them from the `siunitx` parser by placing them inside a group.

I also included a possibility where the parentheses' width is not ignored by actually placing them in the column margin.

I would however prefer the first method, mostly due to clarity. If you need the width of the parentheses, you can manually add it to the margin.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
        group-separator={,},
    ]{siunitx}

% only needed for second version:
\let\beforecell\relax
\let\aftercell\relax
\def\beforeparencell{%
    (%
    \gdef\aftercell{%
        )%
        \global\let\beforecell\relax
        \global\let\aftercell\relax
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=5.0] S[table-format=1.1]}
        12000   &   1.4 \\
        {\llap{(}}14000{\rlap{)}}   &   1.2 
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\beforecell} S[table-format=5.0] @{\aftercell\hspace{2\tabcolsep}} S[table-format = 1.1]}
    12000   &   1.4 {\global\let\beforecell\beforeparencell}\\
    14000   &   1.2 
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\hphantom{(}} S[table-format=5.0] @{\hphantom{)}\hspace{2\tabcolsep}} S[table-format=1.1]}
        12000   &   1.4 \\
        {\llap{(}}14000{\rlap{)}}   &   1.2 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]